# how to click on the second picture

Tags: javascript

my webpage loads 2 things an image and a canvas.

When the page loads the webpages loads the picture.
If I click somewhere the page loads the canvas.

Now I want if I click on the picture somethings happens but how can say onclick -> when the images is been clicked.

I think i can work with an ID in my picture. But how do you give an iD in javascript when creating a picture?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function start() {  
      var vierkant = document.getElementById("Vierkant");  

      initWebGL(vierkant);      // Initialize the GL context  

      // Only continue if WebGL is available and working  

      if (gl) {  
        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 1.0);                      // Set clear color to black, fully opaque  
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);                               // Enable depth testing  
        gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);                                // Near things obscure far things  
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);      // Clear the color as well as the depth buffer.



      }  
    }
function startImage()
{
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "Bus_Stop_2.png"; 
        document.body.appendChild( img );
        img.

}


    function initWebGL(vierkant) {  
      // Initialize the global variable gl to null.  
      gl = null;  

      try {  
        // Try to grab the standard context. If it fails, fallback to experimental.  
        gl = vierkant.getContext("webgl") || vierkant.getContext("experimental-webgl");  
      }  
      catch(e) {}  

      // If we don't have a GL context, give up now  
      if (!gl) {  
        alert("Unable to initialize your 'Vierkant'.");  
      }  
    }  

</script>

    <body onclick="start()" onload="startImage()">  
      <canvas id="Vierkant" width="640" height="480">  
        Your browser doesn't appear to support the HTML5 <code>&lt;canvas&gt;</code> element.  
      </canvas>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this after creating image,

```
img.onclick = function() { alert('image clicked') };
```

You can do your work in place of alert!

Comment: Event handlers in Javascript are case-sensitive, so your code won't work, I'm afraid; it should be `img.onclick`

Comment: Yes i noticed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function startImage()
{
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "Bus_Stop_2.png"; 
        document.body.appendChild( img );
        img.onclick = function (evt) {
            // do something here
        };
}
```

To set the id, you could use: `img.setAttribute('id', 'myid');`